# How to insert data in mysql db using sqlalchemy from django framework?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, sqlalchemy

I am new in django framework and I am trying to make an api for "register" where i want to insert data into db after execution but unable to do so .

I am trying to create the object of auth_user and trying to do `session.add(auth_user_object)`
but  it is not giving any error and even not adding data to mysql db.

I am able to get(fetch) data from db .

all the tables are created .

then i am doing `inspect db` and get the db table class and modify it according to sqlalchemy.

but I am unable to add data to the db tables using sqlalchemy .

please help me.
what is best approach to do so.

my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import *


# Create your models here.
Base = declarative_base()
class Designation(Base):
    __tablename__='designation'
    id = Column(autoincrement=True,primary_key=True) 
    designation_name = Column(String) 
    designation_desc = Column(String) 


class UAuthUser(Base):
    __tablename__='auth_user'
    id = Column(autoincrement=True,primary_key=True)
    password = Column(String)
    last_login = Column(DateTime)
    is_superuser = Column(Integer)
    username = Column(String)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    is_staff = Column(Integer)
    is_active = Column(Integer)
    date_joined = Column(DateTime)
    fcm_token = Column(String)
    designation_id = Column(Integer)
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['designation'], ['designation.id']
```

my views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import render
from designation.models import *
#from designation.serializers import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy.orm
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
from datetime import datetime
import collections
import requests
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import MySQLdb
import mysql.connector

def mysqlconnection(db):
    dialect = 'mysql'

    username = 'root'
    password = ''
    server = 'localhost'
    port = '3306'
    database = db
    url=dialect+'://'+username+':'+password+'@'+server+':'+port+'/'+database
    try:
        engine = create_engine(url)
        Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        return session
    except:
        return ("Could not establish connection")

# def mysqlCursor(db):
#   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='db')
#   cursor = cnx.cursor(raw=True, buffered=True)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def designation(request):
    session = mysqlconnection('hrdb')
    #query = session.query(Designation.id,Designation.designation_name,Designation.designation_desc).all()
    new_designation=Designation(id=3,designation_name='uday',designation_desc='shankar')
    session.add(new_designation)
    session.bulk_save_objects(new_designation)
    #session.commit()
    session.close()
    return Response('query')


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def register(request):
    session = mysqlconnection('hrdb')
    password1 = "jhg$"
    last_login1 = "2017-02-08 16:12:52.822000"
    is_superuser1 = 0
    username1 = "bibek_n"
    first_name1 = "bibek"
    last_name1 = "neupane"
    email1 = "vivek@gmail.com"
    is_staff1 = 0
    is_active1 = 1
    date_joined1 = "2017-02-08 16:12:52.822000"
    fcm_token1 = "abc"
    designation_id1 = 1
    new_user = UAuthUser(password = password1,last_login = last_login1,is_superuser= is_superuser1,username = username1,first_name = first_name1,last_name = last_name1,email = email1,\
        is_staff = is_staff1,is_active = is_active1,date_joined= date_joined1,fcm_token = fcm_token1,designation_id = designation_id1)
    session.add(new_user)
    #query = session.query(AuthUser).insert()
    #session.commit()
    session.close()
    return Response('query')
```

Comment: first read the Django documentation before starting implementation. you don't need to use SQL alchemy .

Answer (score 0):

by mistake i was not giving data type to the Id thats why the error was comming.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use SQL alchemy in Django. Django provide ORM for making database query. also you can define model like this.

```
class UAuthUser(models.Model):
    __tablename__='auth_user'
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_login = models.DateField()
```

refer this link. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I checked every where they were suggesting to use sqlalchemy but I m not able to use it.

Comment: why are you using sqlalchemy in django. means what is the purpose

Comment: You can use Django ORM for making queries like add, update and delete

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Which-is-better-and-why-Djangos-ORM-or-SQLAlchemy